# Any better alternatives to FileSystem API for Chrome Packaged App?

Tags: google-chrome, filesystems, google-chrome-app

Now that the FileSystem API has been retired for Chrome Packaged Apps, I have been rethinking my use of it. Google Chrome has said that they will continue to support it, but it looks like a dead-end in terms of other browsers implementing it, or further tools being developed for it.  I knew it was only a Chrome thing when I started using it, but have found it extremely frustrating to work with because there were no tools like an Explorer-type app, Hex editor, TeamViewer-like file transfers, grep....  I held out hope that someone (maybe me) would work on these basics, but that hope is pretty much dead. So...

Is there a way, or a plan in the works, to give Chrome Packaged Apps access (after some permission setting) to the local OS file system? (I know there is a hack to do this, but I would prefer something mainstream).

Comment: Can you add a source for your retirement claim?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-apps/k39Lb1VYWEI

Comment: But that topic clearly states, _"We'll be keeping the existing API."_. The only thing retired is the current version of the specification.

Comment: I know. The first paragraph is an explanation of why this is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for [official docs](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_storage).

Comment: Just looking for an answer to my question.

Comment: I went with Native Messaging to a system app that works with the local OS.